# Should this question be moved to apple.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

Should this [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/aperture-3-open-first-aid-options-for-external-library) be a candidate for apple.stackexchange.com ?

I am aware that the software mentioned is photography related but feels more like how do I fix this on Apple kind of question. Also moving over to the other side might net more answers for the person who posed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet you a dollar if we migrated it there it wouldn't get answered.

Because I just checked and he's asked it over there!  Two minutes before he asked here.

Good idea though, it's a better fit there I think.  I guess we can close this one

Comment: I don't know... The fact that he got answers here and not there might well indicate that this is the right place! :)

Comment: It's also not attracted a single vote to close (yet) in the month it's been on the site.

Comment: True, one of the first [questions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66993/lightroom-catalog-on-external-hard-drive-not-readable/66994#66994) I answered here was about LR on a Mac, it got migrated to apple so that's why I asked.

Comment: JoanneC: Yes, he got an answer from me, who's never used Apple or Aperture in his life!  And apparently it doesn't work!

Comment: I didn't say it was a good answer, I can go downvote if you want... :p I think you could start the close process on it, migrating it doesn't make sense given it was already asked there, and see if the community agrees. I suspect they will.

Comment: I don't think it hurts to leave it.  Just no point migrating since it's already there

Comment: A couple of us just posted suggestions as well. I'm a Mac user, though I don't use Aperture, but there are other paths into the 1st aid feature.

Comment: JoanneC: Isn't your answer exactly what I (tried to anyway) recommend?

Comment: It is, I'm going blind...

Comment: So close or migrate?

Comment: I don't see migrating it, a more experienced Mod may see different, but the question is already unanswered there. As for here, up to the community I think. I don't see a strong reason to close it and I could see others coming here for such a question, it's logical.